# CSS background image url not showing up

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I can't figure out why this background image does not show up. But when I using `content:url()` it showing up. The problem using `content:url()`, I can't control image size. Bellow I provide the complete the code as your reference.

**Component**

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-reset-password',
      template: `
      <form>
      <h2 class="dialog-form-title">RESET PASSWORD</h2>
      <div class="warning-messages"><span class="warning_image">This User ID will no longer be able to log in with their 
      previous password.</span></div>
      <div class="dialog-form-footer" fxLayoutGap="20px">
        <button mat-flat-button type="submit" [mat-dialog-close]="true" style="margin:5px;background:#2BA9F8;">Confirm</button>
        <button mat-flat-button type="button" [mat-dialog-close]="false" style="margin:5px;background:#D3D3D3">Cancel</button>
      </div>  
    </form>
      `,
      styles: ['.warning-messages{background-color: #FFFEEF; color: #D9B88A; padding: 20px 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-weight: 400; }.warning_image:before{background-image: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crime-and-security-3-5/48/147-128.png");}.warning_image:before{display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;background-size: 12px auto;}']
    })
```

This is [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-confirm-delete)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for your comment.. Sorry!.. I will not repeated it in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For pseudo element you must have to define **content** property.Instead of using **before** you can directly apply background image to **warning-messages** class.

```
.warning-messages{
  background-image: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crime-and-security-3-5/48/147-128.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: How to display image before text and inline?

Comment: You want image above text or side by side?

Comment: I want side by side

Comment: image first and than text

Comment: For side by side, You have to use <img /> instead of background image.